# Angular2: Model driven form validation for confirm password

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

How do we use angular2 validation for password confirmation? I am using angular 2.0 final.

I am using formbuilder class for model driven form as following:

```js
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      email: [''],
      passwordgroup: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        confirm_password: ['', Validators.compose([])]
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You can simply use a custom validator by adding this function to your component like this*

```
 import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

    function passwordConfirming(c: AbstractControl) {
        return c.get('password').value === c.get(' confirm_password').value

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      email: [''],
      passwordgroup: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        confirm_password: ['', Validators.compose([])]
      },  { validator: passwordConfirming })
    });
```

Comment: My entire form (myForm) should be invalid if passwords don't match, right?

Comment: Actually you can not define function like this `function abc(x: X){}` in Angular2. One need to use something similar to this `abc = function(x:X){}`

Comment: @Paresh that is true

Comment: It's giving me syntax error. Anyway regarding validation part, the solution is not working in my case. _myForm_ is valid even if passwords don't match

Comment: Here is the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/R05VPzUm1hGrfLx4dH5P?p=preview). 
Plunker is not working due to some routing issue, but you can see the code

Comment: Make sure the abstract control is imported from @agular/forms in your component.ts file also add the passwordValidator function right after all your import statement like this...                                                           import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';                                                                  passwordValidator = function(g: AbstractControl){
        return g.get('password').value === g.get('confirm_password').value
     }
}

Comment: Can you please tell why PasswordValidator function should be defined just  after import statement?

Comment: Not necessarily... i only just explained exactly how it worked on my side.

Comment: Thanks #ibukunoluwa. Finally !! I got it working... The mistake I was making from day 1 was using `Validator: _passwordValidator_` instead of `validator: _passwordValidator_`. But while **Validator** is part of _@angular/forms_, I don't know from where **validator** is coming from.

Comment: it is like that because we are creating a custom validator as oppose to the default validators that came with angular 2.. if  my answer has helped you..please vote for it by clicking on the vote button. Thanks. glad it is all done now.

Comment: it's not reusable at all, think about a way to make it static and pass a control as a parameter,   newPassword: [ '', ConfirmPasswordValidator.shouldMatch(this.form.find('confirmNewPassword')] . 
p.s. : this code doesn't work

Comment: For last Angular version : passwordConfirming(c: AbstractControl) {
        return (c.get('password').value === c.get('confirmPassword').value) ? null : 'Password mismatch';
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      email: [''],
      passwordgroup: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        confirm_password: ['', Validators.compose([])]
      },  passwordConfirming)
    });
```

Removing the 'validator' key above(doing away with this object notation) and just using validator name 'passwordConfirming' worked without syntax error.